# Reverse engineer my android game + prevention

Tags: java, android, security, reverse-engineering

I have built a very simple game for android mobile.

The game is very simple: 
your supposed to press the screen whenever the screen turns from blue to red.

(the score is based on how fast you pressed, the skilled players with the higher ranks are supposed to be players with a very low reaction times.)

There is a high score board for all players too see.

this delayTime is being sent to a server to store the times for all players.

My questions are:

1) Is it possible for people to reverse engineer my app and actually reducing the variable of the response-delay?  the delay is being measured with a timeStamp:

```
long userDelayTime = timeNow - timeScreenTurnedRed;
```

and then being sent to the server.

If reverse engineering is as easy as people say it is, someone can do the following:

```
long userDelayTime = randomedRidiculouslySmallTime;
```

and gain a huge advantage..

2) How can i avoid this scenario?

3) If i'm planning on recreating this game in a website, will i have the same issue? how can i avoid this scenario in a website?

thanks!

Comment: Don't rely on the client to check anything or to slow things down.  Always check on the server, which you control. i.e. never trust the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) Is it possible for people to reverse engineer my app and actually
>   reducing the variable of the response-delay?

Yes, Absolutely.

> 2) How can i avoid this scenario?

In android application I can't see any option to avoid your problem :S. SomeOne atleast as talented as you can crack it.

> 3) If i'm planning on recreating this game in a website, will i have
>   the same issue? how can i avoid this scenario in a website?

If you create the game in web server, then it will be much more secured. In android someone can recreate your apk using reverse-engineering mechanism. But when the game is in a web server then he has to gain the access so it is definitely much more secured.